# let MS-Word vba ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(2).Select select paragraph 1 only?

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I want to add many hyperlinks via VBA for my MS-Word file, for 1st paragraph the hyperlink is "./index/1.doc", 2nd paragraph is "./index/2.doc", and so on. The simpilfied procedure is 1)select one paragraph 2)add hyperlink, just as the following code says. However, the VBA code gives every paragraph same hyperlink which only should be for the last paragraph. So, is there any way to deselect in VBA to perform this case? Thanks

btw, the VBA can be tested on any MS-Word file with more than 1 paragraphs.

```
Sub addHypertext()
    For countParagraph = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd    
        set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(countParagraph)
        para.Select
        Set paraStyle = para.Style 
        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, \
            Address:="./index/" & countParagraph & ".doc"    

        Rem this does not work 
        Rem Selection.Range.Style = paraStyle 

        Rem this does not work 
        Selection.Style = paraStyle 

        Rem this does not work too 
        Rem para.Style = paraStyle 

        Rem this produces "run-time error" 
        Rem para.Range.Style = "text"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what's happening. It is highlighting the paragraph tag and making it part of the hyperlink. I am curious if maybe you might just want to add a reference at the end of each paragraph instead. See if this is something you might want to try:

```
Sub addHypertext()
    Dim para As Paragraph

    For countParagraph = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(countParagraph)
        para.Range.Select
        Selection.MoveRight 1
        Selection.MoveLeft 1
        Selection.Font.Superscript = True
        Selection.TypeText "[" + Trim(Str(countParagraph)) + "]"
        Selection.MoveLeft Count:=Len("[" + Trim(Str(countParagraph)) + "]"), Extend:=wdExtend

        para.Range.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
            Address:="./index/" & countParagraph & ".doc"

        Selection.Font.Superscript = False
    Next

End Sub
```

The above will put a reference link at the end of each paragraph like wikipedia does on their site.

The following will get the whole paragraph as the link as it looks like you initially wanted:

```
Sub addHypertext()
    Dim para As Paragraph

    For countParagraph = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(countParagraph)
        para.Range.Select
        Selection.MoveEnd Count:=-1

        para.Range.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
            Address:="./index/" & countParagraph & ".doc"

    Next

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

To answer your addition as to styles, the following still keeps the link and changes the style.

```
Sub addHypertext()
    Dim para As Paragraph

    For countParagraph = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(countParagraph)
        para.Range.Select
        Selection.MoveEnd Count:=-1

        para.Range.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
            Address:="./index/" & countParagraph & ".doc"

        para.Range.Select
        Selection.MoveEnd Count:=-1

        'Per your comments below for future visitors
        Selection.Style = "Normal"
        Selection.Style = "My Custom Style"

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. I met anthor sequential question: I don't want to change the paragraph style to 'hyperlink', so I try to keep or change style. But none of the code works. Sorry I don't find how to write code in comment, so I add the code by editing my first post.

Comment: Have you considered the first option? Is that an option?

Comment: I have learned from the 1st VBA code, maybe I will use it later. Currently, the following action: add hyperlink to the whole paragraph and let the use can jump to the reference by clicking the paragraph, which the 2nd VBA does meets my requirement mostly.

Comment: It is so strange that `Selection.Style = "my style"` can not assign this style to the paragraph which has hyperlink. The solution is to call `Selection.Style = "default paragraph style"` (sorry, I don't know the extact name since it is named in my native language) before `Selection.Style = "my style"`. This is weird and tedious.

Comment: Welcome to Word VBA/Interop :-) I could never count the number of hack-arounds I've had to do. It makes for interesting work.